# Validations for Dynamically generated row in a table using javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery

In this context the row which is being generated dynamically is not being validated at row level and also the starting row which is also present before appending rows is not validating simultaneously on clicking the submit button.

```
    $("#addrow").click(function(newid){
            var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element1 = document.createElement("select");

            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "--Select Project--";
            option1.value = "";

            element1.add(option1);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
            option2.value = "2";
            element1.add(option2, null);

            element1.id="project"+(rowCount+1);
            element1.style.width="225px";
            cell2.appendChild(element1);

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "--Select Module--";
            option1.value = "";

            element2.add(option1);
            element2.id="module"+(rowCount+2);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            cell3.appendChild(element2);

            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var element3 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "--Select Sprint--";
            option1.value = "";

            element3.add(option1);
            element3.id="sprint"+(rowCount+2);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
            option2.value = "2";
            element3.add(option2, null);
            cell4.appendChild(element3);

            var cell5= row.insertCell(4);
            var element4 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "--Select Category--";
            option1.value = "";

            element4.add(option1);
            element4.id="category"+(rowCount+3);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
            option2.value = "2";
            element4.add(option2, null );

            cell5.appendChild(element4);

            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var element5 = document.createElement("input");
            element5.type = "text";
            element5.name = "txtbox[]";
            element5.className="spent";
            element5.style.width="50px";
            element5.style.height="15px";

            cell6.appendChild(element5);

            var cell7= row.insertCell(6);
            var element6 = document.createElement("input");
            element6.type = "text";
            element6.name = "txtbox[]";
            element6.className="remain";
            element6.style.width="50px";
            element6.style.height="15px";
            cell7.appendChild(element6);
            $(".spent").spinner({ min: 1, max: 12 });
            $(".remain").spinner({ min: 0, max: 50 });

            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            var element7 = document.createElement("textarea");
            element7.name = "txtbox[]";
            element7.id="comments"+(rowCount+4);
            element7.style.width="95px";
            element7.style.height="30px";

            cell8.appendChild(element7);

            $("#validate").click(function(){
                    var rowcount=table.rows.length;
                    for(var i=1;i<rowcount;){
                            for(var j=1;j<=5;j++){
                                    var project=element1.id;
                                    var module=element2.id;
                                    var sprint=element3.id;
                                    var category=element4.id;
                                    var comments=element7.id;

                                    var prjt=$("#"+project+" option:selected").text();
                                    if(prjt=="--Select Project--"){

                                            alert("please select the project");

                                            return false;

                                    } else{
                                            $("#"+project).css({"border":"#ffffff"});
                                    }

                                    var mdule=$("#"+module+" option:selected").text();
                                    if(mdule=="--Select Module--"){
                                            alert("please select the Module");
                                            $("#"+module).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                                            return false;

                                    } else{
                                            $("#"+module).css({"border":"#ffffff"});
                                    }

                                    var sprnt=$("#"+sprint+" option:selected").text();
                                    if(sprnt=="--Select Sprint--"){
                                            alert("please select the Sprint");
                                            $("#"+sprint).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                                            return false;

                                    } else{
                                            $("#"+sprint).css({"border":"#ffffff"});
                                    }

                                    var catgory=$("#"+category+" option:selected").text();
                                    if(catgory=="--Select Category--"){
                                            alert("please select the Category");
                                            $("#"+category).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                                            return false;

                                    } else{
                                            $("#"+category).css({"border":"#ffffff"});
                                    }

                                    var coments=$("#"+comments).val();
                                    if(coments == ""){
                                            alert("please enter comments");
                                            $("#"+comments).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                                            return false;

                                    } else{
                                            $("#"+comments).css({"border":"#ffffff"});
                                    }
                                    i++; 
                            }
                    }
            });

    return newid;
});

    $("#validate").click(function(){
            function valid(){
                    var projectSearch_projectName=$( ".projectName option:selected" ).text();

                    if (projectSearch_projectName == "--Select Project--") {
                            alert("please select one option");
                            $(".projectName").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                            return false;

                    } else{
                            $(".projectName").css({"border":"#ffffff"});


                    }

                    var module=$( ".module option:selected" ).text();
                    if (module == "--Select Module--") {

                            alert("please select one option");
                            $(".module").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                            return false;

                    } else{
                            $(".module").css({"border":"#ffffff"});


                    }

                    var sprints=$( ".sprints option:selected" ).text();
                    if (sprints == "--Select Sprint--") {

                            alert("please select one option");
                            $(".sprints").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                            return false;

                    } else{
                            $(".sprints").css({"border":"#ffffff"});


                    }
                    var category=$( ".category option:selected" ).text();
                    if (category == "--Select Category--") {

                            alert("please select one option");
                            $(".category").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                            return false;

                    } else{
                            $(".category").css({"border":"#ffffff"});


                    }

                    var comments=$(".comments").val();
                    if (comments == "") {
                            alert("Please enter the Comments");
                            $(".comments").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                            return false;

                    }

                    else 
                    {
                            $(".comments").css({"border":"ffffff"});
                    }
            } 

    });
});
```

Comment: please share a picture of your work

Comment: It is hard to tell from the context of the code presented, but it looks like you attach one click function to `#validate` and then overwrite it later with another. This could just appear this way due to what was supplied as there appears to be incomplete nesting presented.

Comment: Several variables are declared with a var statement after they have already been declared (newid, option1, option2).

Comment: Below listed are the methodologies which i have tried to perform dynamic row validations :
--> First i have tried ajax call as well as struts property to retrieve rows of the table.
 --> after retrieveing the data, i have configured html table
 --> problem started when i have tried to access each cell of each row in the table.
--> To attain this:

Comment: 1) using jquery find, first i have accessed the table and then each row. then i used blur functionality on each cell of the row to validate that cell data and move on to the next cell. but the actual functionality is to validate the data on clicking submit button. also, if the user doesn't enter into that particular row, we cannot get the data or validate it.

2) using jquery closest function, i have accessed the row data but it is not appropriate as it is accesing irrelevant data

Comment: 3) using struts property tag, i have retrieved the count of number of rows in the table and also retrieved the object consisting of the rows in the table, but i'm not able to access the data present in that object. but if we can access individual arrays in that object, then there might be a possibility, to retrieve each value present in that array.

4) using jquery find function, i have accessed column values of a particular table, but these are accessed in the form of a set, it is difficult to segregate the data and perform validation on it.

Comment: 5) by using first and last child functionalities, i have accessed the first and last cells of that row but i'm not able to access the middle cells

Above mentioned are the functionalities that i have used to access the elements of the rows in the table to perform validations, but the problem is not yet resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This code calls `$("#validate").click(function() {` and then later `$("#validate").click(function(){`. The second call isn't adding to the things that are done when `#validate` is clicked, but overwriting the first.

It would be possible to turn those into named functions and then call:

```
$("#validate").click(function() {
    firstFunction();
    secondFunction();
});
```

if you want to keep those two functions separate.